# Meaning of "Bus Privato" on bus timetables for Trentino Trasporti

Tags: public-transport, italy, buses, terminology, timetables

I'm planning a trip to Trento and planning on making several trips there by bus - I've found some timetables on their website (example: https://www.trentinotrasporti.it/pdforari/extraurbani/linee/OrariDiDirettrice-E21I-202INA.PDF) on which some services are marked as "Bus Privato".

This literally seems to translate is "Private Bus". Which presumably means they are not open to the public? If that is the case what purpose do they serve and who are these buses for? They do not seem to correspond to school times and seem to run the same route as other public services, they also don't seem to show on online journey planners. Why include them in the public timetables at all?

Is it possible for members of the public (or large groups?) to pre-arrange to use these services?

Comment: Probably open to the public but operated by a private company, so the government has no responsibility and network cards might not work.

Comment: Absent any warning or information (and I couldn't find any anywhere), I would simply assume this means this bus is operated by a private business, as opposed to Trentino Trasporti itself, which is a company owned by the province and local authorities. Price and conditions may be different but even that is not necessarily the case.

Comment: "they also don't seem to show on online journey planners" at least for the route you cited, the times are available on TT's planner.

Comment: The other columns on the timetable are headed with a blue bus keyed as "Bus TT". So one presumes these are run by Trentino Trasporti and the other by a private company. In UK where I live most bus services are run by the national company Stagecoach, while several local companies operate too, and some timetables include all the services that operate (for the aid of passengers). If they aren't on some 'journey planner' then that's the journey planner of a company who does not want to give away business to a competitor.

Comment: ... so perhaps Bus TT is happy to provide timetable information about other operators but does not take bookings for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Local resident here.

As some commenters pointed out, this is a bus run operated by a private company on behalf of Trentino Trasporti. Apart of the livery of the car, there is basically no difference. You can use the same tickets.

I don't know why they put this note on the timetable, probably to warn tourists that they have to expect a bus with a private company logo instead of the "Trentino Transporti" one.  There will be a paper sign on the windscreen with the logo of "Trentino Trasporti" and the destination. Usually it is quite noticeable, so it's difficult to make mistakes.

Reservation is not possible for individuals; for large groups the best thing would be to call directly Trentino Trasporti for it might be not possible for all routes and hours.